# Django pass context from different apps to one template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have one django project, in which several apps are registered. Each of them renders its own template, all of those extend the same basic template. Now I want to pass data to this one basic template, without having all apps do this. (Which would be quite the overhead to do) I figured doing this using custom template tags, but I am at a complete loss here, regarding possibility and how-to. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: are you using CBV or standard function views ?

Comment: I use function-based views

Comment: see my answer this is a typical use for CBV

Answer (score 1):

create a Mixin and override `get_context_data()`, put there all your common stuff, add this mixin to all your views that need this behaviour

```
class CommonMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommonMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['common_value'] = 'VALUE1'
        return context


class App1View(CommonMixin, ListView):
     ...


class App2View(CommonMixin, CreateView):
    ...
```

if you use function view, write a function that acts as `get_context_data` and use it in each view.

you can create a custom tag, but is possible that this will introduce more computational cost.

Another approach can be to write a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) but this will impact ALL your views.

Comment: Any other way? Adding code to all the apps is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: added a note, anyway my advice is to move to CBV